# Confusion with Bindings & DataContext in ContentTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf

Consider the following style:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="NumberButton" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2"/>
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Label Content="{Binding}" FontSize="20" FontFamily="Consolas"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="OnClicked"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

My goal here was to be able to create multiple buttons, each one representing a number 0-9. For example, here is the button for number 0:

```
<Button Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource NumberButton}" Content="0"/>
```

My understanding of how DataContext works is that if you don't explicitly set it in the XAML, it is supposedly NULL, which instructs the binding to use the parent's DataContext instead. This is transitive, so it would continue to move up each parent until it found an explicitly set DataContext to use.

I'm however confused at how my binding is able to map to the `Content` attribute. I know that `ContentControl`'s default property is the `Content` property, but I never explicitly set the `DataContext` on the `<Button>` element. To me, this would mean that the Button's DataContext is NULL, and thus it would not be able to find the value to display.

Can someone explain how the DataContext of the Button is being referred to when I haven't set it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `DataContext` of the `<ContentTemplate>` is special in that it gets set to the `Content` property of the object the `<ContentTemplate>` is getting applied to.

In this case, the `ContentTemplate` is being applied to a `Button`, so the `DataContext` inside the `ContentTemplate` is set to the `Content` property of that `Button`, and `Button.Content` is set to `"0"`

If you apply this `ContentTemplate` to a different `Button` with a different `Content` property, that `Content` property will be used instead.

Here's a simple example that I hope demonstrates this a bit better.

```
<Button x:Name="OuterButton" Click="Button_Click">
    <!-- // Set DataContext to a string equal to "OuterButton.DataContext" -->
    <Button.DataContext>
        OuterButton.DataContext
    </Button.DataContext>

    <!-- // Set Content to a string equal to "OuterButton.DataContext" -->
    <Button.Content>
        OuterButton.Content
    </Button.Content>

    <Button.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <Button x:Name="InnerButton" Content="InnerButton.Content" Click="Button_Click" />
                <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding }"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Button.ContentTemplate>
</Button>
```

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = sender as Button;
    Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}.DataContext: {1}", btn.Name, btn.DataContext));
    Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}.Content: {1}", btn.Name, btn.Content));
}
```

We have a button here. The Button's `DataContext` and `Content` properties are set to different values. The button also has a `ContentTemplate` defined, which contains another `Button`. This button's `Content` property is set to a different value.

Clicking on either button will output the `Content` and `DataContext` of the button that was clicked. Keep in mind that the inner button is nested inside the OuterButton, so when you click on it, the Click method gets processed for both buttons.

The end result for clicking on the inner button:

```
InnerButton.DataContext: OuterButton.Content
InnerButton.Content: InnerButton.Content

OuterButton.DataContext: OuterButton.DataContext
OuterButton.Content: OuterButton.Content
```

As you can see, a `ContentTemplate` is special in that it sets the `DataContext` to the `Content` property of whatever object it is applied to.

Comment: Rachel, you always make learning WPF so much easier!! I marked yours as the new answer. Thanks a ton, this made it crystal clear for me. This also helped me figure out how to map my Commands properly in my style outside and inside my ContentTemplate, since the data context changes between the two!

Comment: This is good way to modify the content of a button (e.g. add an icon, or additional text) without affecting the buttons appeance (such as hover, disabled state etc)

Answer (score 2):

Your guess is right `default source property for ContentControl is Content`. So by doing this `{Binding}`, you are explicitly telling binding engine to bind content property of Label with Content property of button.

But suppose you want to bind to some property in DataContext of button - **Bind Name property of DummyDataContext**, you have to do this way (*Assuming DummyDataContext is set as DataContext on root window*):

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource CalcButton}" Content="{Binding}"/>
```

and in DataTemplate

```
<Label Content="{Binding Name}" FontSize="20" FontFamily="Consolas"/>
```

Content of Button is pointing to instance of class DummyDataContext. So when you bind `Content="{Binding Name}"` on label, you are telling it to bind with `Name` property on object which is binded to Content of Button.

Hope it makes sense now..!!

Comment: So `{Binding}` doesn't bind to the value of `DataContext`, like I have been reading online? It binds to the default property of the class? I'm hearing so much conflicting information, it confuses the hell out of me :( Also what you are saying directly contradicts what Rachel states in her answer.

Comment: You are confusing things here. I mentioned same what Rachel mentioned in her answer - `The DataContext of the <ContentTemplate> is special in that it gets set to the Content property of the object the <ContentTemplate> is getting applied to.` {Binding} inside ContentTemplate behvaes differently compare to other things you have read.

Answer (score 0):

For most controls, if no `DataContext` is set, it uses the Parent `DataContext`, done via inherited dependency properties. `ContentControls` and derived Controls from that, like a `Button`, work a bit differently. If you set the `Content` of these `Controls` you also set the `DataContext` to the Content. So in your case your `DataContext` is also string "0". Afair setting no `Content` at all will break the inherited chain so your `DataContext` inside that button will be null.

Comment: This change in behavior is dependent on a specific hierarchy I assume? in my specific case, anything driving from ContentControl will automatically set the data context as you have explained? I couldn't find any official documentation on this behavior.

Comment: I have to disagree with your answer. If you set a `Content` property of a `ContentControl`, or controls derived from a `ContentControl` such as a `Button`, it does NOT set the `DataContext` of that control as well. It does however use that `Content` property as the `DataContext` of any `ContentTemplate` applied to that control, which is perhaps what you were thinking of. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20845650/302677) for an example :)

Comment: Yes you are correct, Rachel. Couple of days away from the code, and already starting to forget stuff.