# Access DataContext of element to which style is applied

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following XAML (partial):

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:CalculatorViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>

<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="CalcButton" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2"/>
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Label Content="{Binding}" FontSize="20" FontFamily="Consolas"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding CalcButtonPressed}"/>
        <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding}"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

The issue is my `CommandParameter` being set in the style. I want to pass the value of Content (which is just a simple number 0-9) into my command function. Oddly enough I'm able to bind the Command to `CalculatorViewModel` (in my `Window.DataContext`) just fine, but I don't know how to setup the `CommandParameter` binding to refer back to the `DataContext` of the element to which this style will be applied (which is a Button).

Inside of my `<DataTemplate>` in the style, I'm able to specify `{Binding}` to access the Button's DataContext. I'm still learning the DataContext inheritance behavior, and when you throw styles into the mix it makes things confusing. I'm assuming that Styles ignore normal inheritance and instead looks physically outside of where the Style is placed for DataContext information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need setter like this to pass `Content` property of Button:

```
<Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding Content,
                                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
```

**Explanation**:

1. If you do simply `{Binding}`, that will pass `DataContext` of Button which is instance of CalculatorViewModel.
2. If you do `{Binding Content}` - it will search for Content property in DataContext of Button i.e. in CalcualtorViewModel.
3. So, with `RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}`, you are telling binding engine to look for property `Content` on button and not in its DataContext.

By default `{Binding Path=AnyProperty}` will search for `AnyProperty` in its DataContext.

Comment: My understanding of `ContentControl` is that when you set the `Content` property on the control, that (indirectly) sets the `DataContext` to the value of `Content` as well. In that respect, I wouldn't expect it to inherit the value of the Window's data context. How else would the `{Binding}` usage inside of the `<Label>` be able to obtain the value of the Button's `Content`? I didn't bind to `Content` there...

Comment: No, setting Content doesn't set DataContext to content.

Comment: And for ContentControl content binding, check out my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20835325/632337).

Comment: Also, if that would have been case then how this works `<Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding CalcButtonPressed}"/>`. CalcButtonPressed command resided in your ViewModel and you was able to resolve that. It means DataContext of button is set to `CalcualtorViewModel` and not `Content`.